# Enable https on localhost on WildFly 9.0.1 release

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

I am trying to run localhost in secure mode `https://localhost:8080`

I have done some changes to standalone xml as below

```
<security-realm name="SSLRealm">
    <server-identities>
        <ssl protocol="TLS">
            <keystore path="serverkeystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="secureworld" alias="servercert"/>
        </ssl>
    </server-identities>
    <authentication>
        <truststore path="servertruststore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="secureworld"/>
    </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

and

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="5000"/>
<https-listener name="default-https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SSLRealm" verify-client="REQUESTED" max-parameters="5000"/>
```

The web xml is have

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <path>/</path>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Then I tried to start the server, I think it is missing keystore file

```
09:45:14,889 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.SSLRealm.key-manager: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.SSLRealm.key-manager: WFLYDM0086: The KeyStore can not be found at C:\work\Servers\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\serverkeystore
    at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeystore.load(FileKeystore.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeyManagerService.start(FileKeyManagerService.java:145)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar:1.2.6.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar:1.2.6.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
```

could some one help me to fix this.

Comment: where is your keystore file located?

Comment: @ctomc. Thank you for response. I realized that I was missing key store file. I generated that using http://blog.eisele.net/2015/01/ssl-with-wildfly-8-and-undertow.html

Comment: For future reference on SO, it would be cool to answer your own question with an overview of the steps to take to solve this issue.